# How to automatically answer "more" command

Tags: bash

For the following script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

more <<_EOF_
  PLEASE READ THE TERMS OF THIS AGREEMENT AND ANY PROVIDED TEXT.   PLEASE READ THE TERMS OF THIS AGREEMENT AND ANY PROVIDED TEXT.   PLEASE READ THE TERMS OF THIS AGREEMENT AND ANY PROVIDED TEXT.   PLEASE READ THE TERMS OF THIS AGREEMENT AND ANY PROVIDED TEXT.   PLEASE READ THE TERMS OF THIS AGREEMENT AND ANY PROVIDED TEXT.   PLEASE READ THE TERMS OF THIS AGREEMENT AND ANY PROVIDED TEXT.   PLEASE READ THE TERMS OF THIS AGREEMENT AND ANY PROVIDED TEXT.   PLEASE READ THE TERMS OF THIS AGREEMENT AND ANY PROVIDED TEXT.   PLEASE READ THE TERMS OF THIS AGREEMENT AND ANY PROVIDED TEXT.   PLEASE READ THE TERMS OF THIS AGREEMENT AND ANY PROVIDED TEXT.   PLEASE READ THE TERMS OF THIS AGREEMENT AND ANY PROVIDED TEXT
_EOF_

agreed=
while [ x$agreed = x ]; do
    echo
    echo "Do you accept all the terms?"
    echo "Do you agree to the above license terms? [y/n] "
    read reply leftover
    case $reply in
    y* | Y*)
        agreed=1;;
    n* | n*)
        echo "If you don't agree to the license you can't install this sofware";
        exit 1;;
    esac
done
```

How do you automatically skip the `more` command?

`printf "y\n" | bash ./file.sh` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: as an aside, don't follow the practices you see in that script. `[ x$foo = x ]` is an artifact of the 1970s (and buggy if the user enters, say, `*`, or `1\ =\ x1\ -o\ x` -- the backslashes prevent `read` from splitting content into `leftover`, since `-r` wasn't used); in any shell that's even a _tiny_ bit modern (read: from the 90s or later), `[ -z "$foo" ]` or `[ ! -n "$foo" ]` is preferred.

Comment: Personally, I'd probably fix this by passing options to `more` through the environment. For example, `MORE=e` tells it not to wait for the user to press `q` after it hit end-of-file, `LINES` can be set to tell it how long to treat the terminal as being, &c.

Comment: Agreed! Unfortunately, it is a 3rd party vendor with a binary file. :( They are the cheapest vendor by at least 4 times. As a result, this is what I have to work with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
(more() { :; }; export -f more; script)
```

and `more` won't show up.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `more() { cat }`? Otherwise `more` would not only not ask for confirmation, but also don't print the text.

Comment: "skip the more command" in OP

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
 { sleep 1; echo y; sleep 1; } | bash ./script.sh
```

I use:

```
more from util-linux 2.37.2
```

Comment: Does this actually work? `more` is getting the content to display from stdin connected to a temporary file created from the heredoc, so I'd think it would need to be reading user input direct from the TTY, not on stdin.

Comment: Yes, tested, works

Comment: Interesting; I'm curious as to how. (Not _quite_ curious enough to strace it, but curious nonetheless). Similarly, curious how portable that is across `more` implementations.

Comment: ...okay, [POSIX says](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/more.1p.html) that `more` should read commands from stderr when it's a terminal, and _may_ fall back to `/dev/tty` otherwise. Which... I'd take to mean that this answer probably wouldn't work with a strictly compliant implementation.

Comment: FreeBSD 'more' was aliased to 'less'. Not that curious as Charles for this.

Answer (score -3):

To automatically respond to the "more" command in a program or script, you would typically need to implement a pagination mechanism.

```py
def paginate(items, page_size=10):
    """Paginate a list of items."""
    for i in range(0, len(items), page_size):
        yield items[i:i+page_size]

def display_page(page):
    """Display a page of items."""
    for item in page:
        print(item)

# Example list of items
items = [f"Item {i}" for i in range(1, 101)]

# Paginate the list
pages = paginate(items)

# Loop to display pages until there are no more
for page in pages:
    display_page(page)
    if input("Press Enter to see more, or type 'exit' to quit: ").lower() == 'exit':
        break
```

Comment: What you've shown here is code to implement _a copy of_ `more`, not to control a copy of `more` provided by the local OS vendor. We don't allow LLM-generated answers in no small part because they're often this kind of plausibly-stated irrelevancy.